# jqGrid event handler for clearing filter toolbar textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I've done some searching and can't seem to find the solution to my problem here. I need to capture the event that happens when the user clicks the X to clear a textbox input in a jqGrid filter toolbar. I am using free-jqGrid 4.13.1.

Here's the code I'm using to set up my filter toolbar. This is a global method that is used to create the filter toolbar for all jqGrids in my project.

```
var bindTableFilterToolbar = function (table, selector) {
    table.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        defaultSearch: 'cn'
        , ignoreCase: true
        , stringResult: true
        , searchOnEnter: false
        , afterSearch: function () {
            var filteredRows = $('#' + selector + ' tr').filter(':not(.jqgfirstrow)');
            if (filteredRows.length === 1) {
                table.jqGrid('setSelection', filteredRows[0].id);
            }
        }
        , afterClear: function() {
            alert('this does not trigger');
        }
    });
}
```

Here's a screenshot to show exactly what I mean.

[image: Filter Toolbar Image]

For this particular grid, the `datatype` is set to json but the `URL` property is set and therefore after the AJAX request, I know it sets to `local`. I am requesting unfiltered data from the server with `loadonce: true`.

How do I tie in to the event for the user clicking the X to clear the textbox? I've tried adding the `afterClear` handler, but that doesn't seem to be firing upon clicking the X. After looking [on the trirand wiki for toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) I think that `afterClear` is for clearing the entire toolbar, which is *not* what I need.

Comment: Which version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) you use? Could you included the code where you tried `afterClear`? Do you tried call `alert` inside of `afterClear`? Which `datatype` you use? Do you reload *local data* or request unfiltered data *from the server*? What behavior exactly you want to implement? Do you want to select the first row of the grid in case of filtering or always or in case of some other conditions? Why you don't use `loadonce: true`? There are many ways to select the row you should just provide more information about jqGrid, which you create.

Comment: @Oleg, I have added the details you requested in my question above. Regarding the behavior, I want to capture the event of clearing the input box upon clicking the X. I don't need to capture one specific box, in fact I need to capture clicking the X for any of the filter toolbar inputs. I'm not concerned with selecting any row. I already know how to do that.

Comment: I suppose that you still incorrectly formulate your requirements. You wrote "I want to capture the event of clearing the input box upon clicking the X", but you **don't specified what you want to do inside of the event handler**. I can answer on your direct question, but I suppose that it will be *not* what you want. By default jqGrid calls `triggerToolbar` (if default `autosearch: true` option of `filterToolbar` is used), which calls `beforeSearch` for example. That I repeat: please, describe more detailed what you need to do inside of the event handler on click on "X" button.

Comment: @Oleg sorry for the delay on response. What you say here works well for what I need. :) I can just tap in to the triggerToolbar call to do what I need to.

Comment: OK! I'm glad that I could help you.